# How to extract any specific Error message from Traceback?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the error message displayed in last line. I could able to do it by splitting.

```
test_str = """Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
        yield
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 593, in run
        self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 550, in _callTestMethod
        method()
    File "/Users/abcd/efgh/ijkl/bin/../tests/abd/dummy/dummy1.py", line 95, in test_abc
        assert False, "FAILING FOR A REASON"
    AssertionError: FAILING FOR A REASON """
    
    last_line = test_str.split("\n")[-1]
    print(last_line.split(":")[-1])
```

How can I achieve the same with a regular expression?
It can contain any type of error, `AssertionError, AttributeError, TypeError, SyntaxError` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a regex for that? It doesn't add any value here.

```py
print(re.split(":", last_line, 1)[-1])
```

Perhaps somewhat more usefully,

```py
matched = re.match(r'^\s*([^:\s]+):(.*)', last_line)
if matched:
    error, message = matched.groups()
```

`\s` matches any whitespace character, `*` says repeat zero or more times; `[^:\s]` matches any character which isn't whitespace or a colon, and we repeat that up through just before the first colon.

In slightly higher-level terms, this finds a line which contains a colon after the first stretch of non-space (and non-colon) characters, and extracts the token before the colon, and everything after it, as two separate groups. (The second group will contain any whitespace after the colon, too; maybe add `\s*` before the opening parenthesis to trim any leading spaces.)

But again, if you can do this without regex, do that; using one just makes this slower and more complicated.

If you want to pull out a traceback from a longer piece of text, try

```py
re.match(r''''^Traceback \(most recent call last\):
(?: File "[^\n]+", line \d+, in [^\n]+
  [\n]+
)*([^:]+):([^\n]+)''', many_lines, re.MULTILINE)
```

but this is untested and probably needs some modification to work on samples which are not exactly like the one you shared (in particular, errors from code which isn't in a file will look slightly different; but I also notice your sample traceback does not look like a standard one, because the spacing patterns are slightly different - this regex targets the standard format).

Perhaps notice how we use a `'''...'''` triple-quoted string to embed literal newlines into the regular expression; we still use the `r` sigil to mark this as a raw string, so that we don't have to double all the backslashes.

The `re.MULTILINE` flag is a modifier which changes the meaning of the `^` anchor; with the flag, it matches at the beginning of any line (whereas without the flag, it only matches at the beginning of the input string).

Comment: I meant regex on 'test_str' not on 'last_line'. Last line can contain any of these AssertionError, AttributeError, TypeError, SyntaxError etc

Comment: Splitting the text into lines makes more sense _before_ you apply the regex. But just add a `re.MULTILINE` flag to the second example to apply it to the full `test_str`. Probably [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67295656/edit) to clarify your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the first line, followed by all lines that do not start with either Traceback or a word ending on Error to prevent overmatching.

```
^Traceback \(most recent call last\):(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*(?:Traceback|\w*Error)\b).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*(\w*Error:.*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `Traceback \(most recent call last\):` Match `Traceback (most recent call last):`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?![^\S\r\n]*(?:Traceback|\w*Error)\b)` Assert that the line does not start with `Traceback` or a word ending on `Error`
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*` Match a newline, optional whitespace chars without a newline
- `(\w*Error:.*)` Capture **group 1**, match optional word chars and `Error:` followed by the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LLQMj/1)

For example:

```
import re

test_str = """Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
        yield
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 593, in run
        self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 550, in _callTestMethod
        method()
    File "/Users/abcd/efgh/ijkl/bin/../tests/abd/dummy/dummy1.py", line 95, in test_abc
        assert False, "FAILING FOR A REASON"
    AssertionError: FAILING FOR A REASON """

pattern = r"^Traceback \(most recent call last\):(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*(?:Traceback|\w*Error)\b).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*(\w*Error:.*)"

match = re.match(pattern, test_str)

if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Output

```
['AssertionError: FAILING FOR A REASON ']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/6Uo8XK)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

test_str = """Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
        yield
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 593, in run
        self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 550, in _callTestMethod
        method()
    File "/Users/abcd/efgh/ijkl/bin/../tests/abd/dummy/dummy1.py", line 95, in test_abc
        assert False, "FAILING FOR A REASON"
    AssertionError: FAILING FOR A REASON """


match = re.search(r'(?<=Error:.)(.*)(?=.$)', test_str)
print(match.group(1))
# FAILING FOR A REASON
```